# How to use ensure_inclusion_of for an arbitrary list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, shoulda

In my rails project I have a model with attribute foo. I have a vaildation which ensures that any value for foo is in an array. This uses a validation with the :in option.

I want to test this using rspec/shoulda. I think ensure_inclusion_of is supposed to test this validation but it only works on ranges and not an array. How can I make it work with an array or write my own matcher to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ensure_inclusion_of` is for checking whether Modules are included in the current class.

If you wish to test `validates_inclusion_of` you can either write RSpecs for this yourself, or install the [Shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) and use it's macros.

Here I validate the `gender` field on a user model.

```
describe User do

  it { should validate_presence_of(:gender) }
  it { should allow_value("male").for(:gender) }
  it { should allow_value("female").for(:gender) }
  it { should_not allow_value("other").for(:gender) }

end
```

Comment: I was referring to this matcher: http://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/master/Shoulda/Matchers/ActiveRecord:ensure_inclusion_of   

However your solution seems adequate for my needs.

Comment: Ah, I see. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 3):

You can now write it like this:

```
it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:gender).in_array(%w(male female)) }
```